# matweb.com: How to get source of page?

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I have url like:
http://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=849e2916ab1541be9ff6a17b78f95c82

I want to download source code from that page using this code:

```
private static string urlTemplate = @"http://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=";

static string GetSource(string guid)
{
    try
    {
        Uri url = new Uri(urlTemplate + guid);

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "GET";               

        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        String result = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I do so I get:

> You do not seem to have cookies enabled. MatWeb Requires cookies to be enabled.

Ok, that I understand, so I added lines:

```
CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();  
webRequest.CookieContainer = cc;
```

I got:

> Your IP Address has been restricted due to excessive use. The problem may be compounded when an IP address may be shared by many people in a company or through an internet service provider. We apologize for any inconvenience.

I can understand this but I'm not getting this message when I try to visit this page using web browser. What can I do to get the source code? Some cookies or http headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably doesn't like your UserAgent. Try this:

```
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"; //maybe substitute your own in here
```

Comment: Oh thanks! That works :). BTW how can I get my own UserAgent?

Comment: To get the UserAgent that your browser sends, try something like this site: http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing something that the company doesn't like, if you got an "excessive use" response.

Comment: He said that he's getting this message only when trying to run his program. So his IP is not the issue.

Comment: Looks like it's the user-agent, see above.

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading pages too fast.

When you use a browser you might get up to one page per second. Using a application you can get several pages per second and that's probably what their web server is detecting. Hence the excessive usage.

Comment: That is not true because I get this message even if I run this function once. So too fast townloading is not the problem.